# Cuda 6.0 issue after update

Tags: macos, cuda

I've installed CUDA 6 on my mac. However, nvcc --version is still saying that it's version 5. How can I purge the old version?

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2012 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep_28_16:10:16_PDT_2012
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.1221
```

uder /Developer/NVIDIA/ I have both versions present

```
CUDA-5.0/ CUDA-6.0/
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html#install):

> Set up the required environment variables:
>
> export PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.0/bin:$PATH
>
> export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.0/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH